# How to go about proving that $(\frac{n}{3})^n$ $\leq$ $\frac{n!}{3}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$

Tags: inequality, factorial

I've been stuck on this proof for a long time. I don't even really know where to start.

I've tried simplifying the inequality to:

$$\frac{n^n}{3^{n-1}} \leq n!.$$

But I couldn't find any leads to follow there. Could someone give me a hint on where to go from here. I'm just so lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Induction on $n$ works like a charm, using the elementary upper bound $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\leqslant3$ for every $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: Interestingly, rather than following the hint in the comment above or digesting the correct answer below, you quasi instantly accepted the flagrantly false "answer" you had just received. Did you at least check it? Already its first line is wrong. (Please note that regulars of the site are not surprised that it is, coming from this user.)

Comment: Boy I'm really messing up everything tonight. I should have looked at that answer more carefully. That's my fault, I need to be better about properly understanding the answers. I won't let this happen again.

Comment: It is 9 am here, good morning :P

Comment: Good morning to you, thank you for your answer to my question. I really appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: @Did: 'quasi instantly' - that bombed!

Comment: Could this be thought of as similar to proving that $\left(\dfrac{n}{3}\right)^n$ is $\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{n!}{3}\right)$? Could the limits be used? i.e. if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n}{3}\right)^n}{\dfrac{n!}{3}}$ is a constant, then the inequality holds. Just a thought.

Comment: @an4s The question is about finite $n$ cases, not limits when $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n=3k \ge 3$ (the other cases can be done similarly), then
\begin{align}
n!=(3k)!&\ge (3k)(3k-1) \cdots (k) \\
&= (2k)\prod_{i=1}^k (2k+i)(2k-i)\\
&\ge (2k)\prod_{i=1}^k (2k+k)(2k-k)\\
&=(2k)(3k^2)^k \\
&= (2\cdot 3^k) k^{3k}\\
& \ge (2\cdot 3) k^{3k} \\
&>3 \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n.
\end{align}

Comment: Some terms in the product in the first line could be non-integer. Is this certainly not a problem?

Comment: @Alex With "the other cases", I was referring to "non-multiples of $3$"..

Comment: I got it. So there's no single solution, i.e. for all $n$.

Comment: Not as it is. But minor modifications work with noninteger $k$: note that $$\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}\le \frac{f(n+2)}{f(n)}<2n$$ for all $n$, where $f(n):=(\frac{n}{3})^n$. Then, setting $k=\lfloor n/3\rfloor$,
$$
n! \ge (3k!) \ge (2\cdot 3^k) k^{3k} (k-1)! \ge 9k\cdot k^{3k} \ge f(n).
$$

Comment: ah good one, thanks @Paolo